# About $U(1)_A$ symmetry,

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

I know a $U(1)_A$ symmetry is related with a global symmetry. (Is it axial or anomaly ) What is A stands for?

In the context of supersymmertry, Fundamental and anti-fundamental chiral multiplet has $U(1)_A$ symmetry. What is the meaning of this sentence? 
Is it say each of them has $U(1)_A$ symmetry? or the combined sets of Fundamental and antifundamental multiplet has $U(1)_A$ symmetry?

Comment: Where did you read these things? Can you give a reference?

Comment: In some papers dealing with seiberg duality, $i.e$  $SU(N)$ $SQCD$, with $F$ flavor, where $F<N$, has an $SU(F)\times SU(F)\times U(1)_A \times U(1)_R $ global symmetry.

Comment: $U(1)_{A}$ symmetry just means that you have theory of massless fermions $a_{1}, a_{2}, ...$ which is invariant under set of transformations $a_{i} \to e^{i\alpha \gamma_{5}}a_{i}$. It is an axial symmetry.